# HBaseTestingUtility - changing logging level

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, junit, logback

We use `HBaseTestingUtility` to unit-test HBase related code. The problem is that an output gets populated with **tons of `org.apache.hadoop.*` DEBUG messages**, while executing unit tests.

```
HBaseTestingUtility utility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
utility.startMiniCluster();
```

I've tried different things (configuring log4j etc.) to set the logging level to INFO or WARN - but no success. Also googling did not help to find a solution.

Any idea how to change logging level for Hadoop clases?

Thank you!

*Note: Below are few example debug messages from the logs:*

`...
15:37:14.398 [IPC Server handler 8 on 45239] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server - IPC Server handler 8 on 45239: responding to org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.getFileInfo from 127.0.0.1:41140 Call#1757 Retry#0
15:37:14.398 [IPC Server handler 8 on 45239] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server - IPC Server handler 8 on 45239: responding to org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.getFileInfo from 127.0.0.1:41140 Call#1757 Retry#0 Wrote 33 bytes.
...`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `logback.xml` configuration. E.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```